# XHTML+XML plus XSL plus jQuery don't work in safari

Tags: jquery, xhtml, safari

This is my XHTML/PHP file:

```
<? header('Content-type: application/xhtml+xml')?>
<?="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"?>
<?="<?xml-stylesheet type=\"text/xsl\" href=\"ie-fix.php\"?>"?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8" />
</head> 
<body>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("body").html("test");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the XSL/PHP file (`ie-fix.php`):

```
<? header('Content-type: text/xsl')?>
<?="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8"></xsl:output>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:copy-of select="node()"></xsl:copy-of>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I created it as explained here: http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/2004/xhtml-faq#ie

My code doesn't work in Safari 5.0, the errors I'm getting are:

```
TypeError: Result of expression 'd.style' [null] is not an object.
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $
```

Could anyone help, please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to escpae the dollar sign or